# Можно присвоить 4 разные значения, четырем лейблам в одной строке?

Tags: c#, winforms

Можно присвоить 4 разные значения, четырем лейблам в одной строке?

Например нужно присвоить значения: `24`, `22`, `18`, `8` четырем лейблам (`label1`, `label2`, `label3`, `label4`) в одной строке?

И еще второй вопрос: Как присвоить четырем лейблам одно значение, в одной строке?
Например нужно присвоить четырем лейблам следующее: `Central Areas`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Зачем вам это? Понятность кода от этого не улучшится. Но если очень хочется, то в C# 7+ используйте

```
(label1.Text, label2.Text, label3.Text, label4.Text) = ("24", "22", "18", "8");
```

Присвоить одинаковое значение ещё проще:

```
label1.Text = label2.Text = label3.Text = label4.Text = "Central Areas";
```

---

Кстати, в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct) деконструкция кортежей в *уже существующие переменные* упоминается лишь вскользь, и не показана ни на одном примере. Поэтому этой возможностью пользуются пока не так часто.

---

Оставаясь в рамках C# 4, вы можете сделать такой хак. Присвоение `label1.Text = "24"` является *выражением*. Выражения можно сцепить, чтобы они поместились в одну строку, например, приведя их к типу `bool`:

```
((label1.Text = "24") == null) & ((label2.Text = "22") == null) &
((label3.Text = "18") == null) & ((label4.Text = "8") == null)
```

Чтобы компилятор не ругался на отдельно стоящее выражение, результат можно присвоить переменной:

```
bool dummy = ((label1.Text = "24") == null) & ((label2.Text = "22") == null) &
             ((label3.Text = "18") == null) & ((label4.Text = "8") == null);
```

(Я использовал `&` вместо `&&`, потому что в этом случае не используется сокращённое вычисление (short-circuiting).)

Comment: Можно поподробнее про первый вариант? Что это? Как это? Откуда оно? Я, кажется, что то пропустил :)

Comment: @tym32167: Ну это tuple deconstruction. Более красивый пример: `(a, b) = (b, a);`

Comment: @tym32167 это кортежи ValueTuple, и их деконструирование

Comment: `(label1.Text, label2.Text, label3.Text, label4.Text) = ("24", "22", "18", "8");`  А для C# 4.0 есть что-то подобное?   Поподробнее, сейчас код  выглядит вот так: `labelChance11.Text = "24";
                    labelChance21.Text = "22";
                    labelChance31.Text = "18";
                    labelChance41.Text = "8";`    а нужно написать код одной строкой

Comment: @tym32167: То есть левая часть — это как бы не tuple, хотя выглядит так же.

Comment: @Razi85: А откуда такая необходимость? Почему не записать просто в одну строку без переводов строки? Возможно, вам нужно поместить ваши labelX в контейнер (хотя бы и массив).

Comment: @VladD: `(label1.Text, label2.Text, label3.Text, label4.Text) = ("24", "22", "18", "8");` А для C# 4.0 есть что-то подобное?

Comment: @VladD Спасибо! Я ещё не перешел на новомодный синтаксис, потому спрашиваю. Весьма прикольная фича :)

Comment: @tym32167: Кстати, в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples) есть только deconstructing declaration, но не deconstructing assignment. Но оба пути есть тут: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/

Comment: @Razi85: Нету. Но раз вам нужно массовое присвоение, возможно, вам нужно добавить все ваши label в массив.

Comment: @VladD погоди, погоди, это что, теперь swap без третьей переменной делать можно? :) Всё, ушел читать доки

Comment: @tym32167: Даааааа!

Comment: @Razi85: Смотрите обновление ответа.

Comment: @VladD: Тоже вариант. Но если используется s1, s2, s3, s4, тогда их нужно объявлять и в конце присваивать это значение лейблу. Например: сначала `string s1 = "0";` а после выражения `bool dummy = ((s1 = "24") == null) & ((s2 = "22") == null) &
             ((s3 = "18") == null) & ((s4 = "8") == null);` нужно присвоить лейблу переменную s1. Вот так: `labelChance11.Text = s1;` Или можно попроще: объявить и присвоить переменные?

Comment: @Razi85: Тьфу, ошибся. Вместо `s1` нужно читать `label1.Text` :) Исправил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Не в одну, конечно, строку, но если label'ов будет очень много, то можно в цикле:

```
string[] array = new string[4] {"1","2","3","4"};

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   this.Controls["label" + (i + 1).ToString()].Text = array[i];
```

Comment: Тогда для четырех лейблов: labelChance11, labelChance21, labelChance31, labelChance41 как прописать цикл?  Вот так подойдет? `string[] array = new string[4] { "24", "22", "18", "8" };
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 10; i < 42; i+=10, j++)
                this.groupBox2.Controls["labelChance" + (i + 1)].Text = array[j];`

Comment: @Razi85, параметры цикла такие же как и в моём ответе, а тело так: `this.groupBox2.Controls["labelChance" + (i + 1).ToString() + "1"].Text = array[i];`

Answer (score 0):

Еще можно через метод делать, хоть это и не лучший вариант.

```
public void SetLabelValue(String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4)
    {
        labelChance11.Text = s1;
        labelChance21.Text = s2;
        labelChance31.Text = s3;
        labelChance41.Text = s4;
    }
```

и после вставить в коде туда, где нужно присваивать лейблам значения:

```
SetLabelValue("24", "22", "18", "8");
```